Android studio can't resolve files for configuration ':classpath'
When I try to run my project in Android Studio, I encounter the following error:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyProject'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

The error lists multiple dependencies with their download links, but instead of automatically downloading them, Android Studio immediately throws errors.
For example, the error states:
> Could not find databinding-ktx-8.7.3.aar (androidx.databinding:databinding-ktx:8.7.3).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-ktx/8.7.3/databinding-ktx-8.7.3.aar

This behavior is strange because:
1.If I manually click the download links, the files can be downloaded without any issues.
2.Android Studio appears to skip the download process entirely and shows these red errors within milliseconds.
A snippet of the full error output is:
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform databinding-ktx-8.7.3.aar (androidx.databinding:databinding-ktx:8.7.3) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not find databinding-ktx-8.7.3.aar (androidx.databinding:databinding-ktx:8.7.3).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-ktx/8.7.3/databinding-ktx-8.7.3.aar


Similar errors are listed for other dependencies like navigation-common, material, and appcompat.
what I have done is:
I have checked my connection, no problem with that.
I have removed cache of gradle.
I have uninstall and re-install the android studio.
Also deleted all caches of android studio and gradle cache and sdk folder and let android studio to download them again.
I have also changed sdk version of my project from 20 to 35 and cleaned build and rebuild the project with each sdk version.
I have also tried clean build and invalidate cache in android studio.
I used to change ndk and build tools.
Despite these steps, the issue persists. It seems Android Studio is not attempting to download the dependencies at all.

Did you make sure that you are using the latest versions of Gradle and the Android Gradle plugin?
